# Why does delete not work on array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to delete an array part.

### Did not work

```js
delete my_array[index];
```

### Did work

```js
my_array.splice(index, 1);
```

When looking at the array it looks fine in both cases in the console.log but the first one crashed my app.

*I'm not sure if Vue that I'm using are treating these differently*

**Why does the last one work, but not the first?**

Comment: It does work, but it does something very different than `splice` - which comes from the fact that `delete` is really defined in general for objects and has no special behavior for arrays

Comment: The "_special behavior_" UnholySheep refers is reindexing, `delete` doesn't reindex the array it was used on, it leaves you with a sparse array, where as `splice` reindexes the array if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `delete` operator doesn't affect the length of the array, since it results in setting the element at this index as `undefined`.

```js
new Vue({
  data() { return { array: [1,2,3] } },
  created() { delete this.array[1]; console.log(this.array[1]); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: `delete` doesn't set the value of deleted index to `undefined`, instead the index is removed, causing empty slots occurring into the array.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), The JavaScript `delete` operator removes a property from an object. Same page section `Deleting array elements` suggesting to use `splice` as you used in your 2nd case.

Alternatively `delete` array element

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];


const deleteByIndex = (arr, index) => arr.filter((_, i) => i !== index);

console.log(deleteByIndex(arr, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how change detection works in Vue. At object creation getters and setters are created for each property. As soon as you update it the change will be detected.

Directly adding or deleting goes past this system and will break your app.

This is described in more detail here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Oh, I did not mention but I use Vue 3 and they have fixed reactivity issues with arrays there.